# Как поменять цвет форм в c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть основная форма, то есть меню моей программы.
Создал две кнопки, отвечающие за тему программы, темная или светлая.
`this.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateGray;` работает только для первой формы.
Как мне можно реализовать смену цвета Form2, чтобы когда я открыл её, цвет был другой.
В button_click добавил вот такой код

```
           F[1].BackColor = Color.FromName("DarkSlateGray");//Меняем цвет в шифровке
           F[1].Controls["button1"].BackColor = Color.FromName("DarkSlateBlue");//главная форма в этой коллекции первая, ее индекс 0, меняем ее цвет
           F[2].BackColor = Color.FromName("DarkSlateGray");//главная форма в этой коллекции первая, ее индекс 0, меняем ее цвет
```

Но он меняет цвет только когда форма 1 и 2 открыты, а я хочу чтобы когда я открыл Form1 или Form2 сразу был другой цвет, измененный ранее по нажатию кнопки

Answer (score 0):

Просто как вариант - кнопки меняют режим `bool isDarkMode` на true или false, а при загрузке формы проверяется установлен тёмный режим или светлый

```
void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isDarkMode = true;
    Form1.BackColor = Color.FromName("DarkSlateGray");
    Form1.Controls["button1"].BackColor = Color.FromName("DarkSlateBlue");
    Form2.BackColor = Color.FromName("DarkSlateGray");
}
void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isDarkMode = false;
    Form1.BackColor = Color.FromName("LightGray");
    Form1.Controls["button1"].BackColor = Color.FromName("LightGray");
    Form2.BackColor = Color.FromName("LightGray");
}
void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isDarkMode)
    {
        Form2.BackColor = Color.FromName("DarkSlateGray");
    }
}
```

Comment: ```void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isDarkMode)
    {
        Form2.BackColor = Color.FromName("DarkSlateGray");
    }
}``` надо вставлять же во вторую форму? Потому что, вылезает ошибка что isDarkMode не существует в данном контексте

Comment: а вы переменную создали?)

Comment: Yes)
Создал переменную до событий кнопок)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте параметр(ы) в конструкторе второй формы. Например, так:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Color backColor)
    {
        this.BackColor = backColor;
    }
}
```

И при создании этой формы задавайте нужное значение:

```
var form2 = new Form2(Color.DarkSlateGray);
form2.Show();
```

Для справки: свойство `BackColor` относится к так называемым [AmbientProperties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties?view=net-5.0). Если оно не задано явно, то берётся значение родительского контрола. Следовательно, достаточно задать значение свойству формы и все помещённые на эту форму контролы тоже получат это значение (если оно не переопределено конкретно в них).